# Output RTF special characters to Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, rtf

I have been looking around ocn Google and Stackoverflow but haven't found what I needed, but my question seems quite simple. Anyhow;

What is the way to convert a string of RTF special characters such as "\'d3\'d6" (In this case Russian) to unicode chars or string using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

any of the following should help:

- [Rich Text Format (RTF) Specification, version 1.6, Special Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283%28office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_specialchar). according to this, `\'d3\'d6` are *hexadecimal value[s], based on the specified character set*. so you could write your own processing function, like splitting the the string at `\'`s, converting hex to char, rejoining it, converting to unicode.
- [How to: Convert RTF to Plain Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx)
- [NRTFTree - A class library for RTF processing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx)
- [Questions on SO tagged rtf and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=rtf%2bc%23&sort=votes)
- [Google search "rtf c#"](http://www.google.com/search?q=RTF+c%23)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those characters:

```
int findUTF = -1;
bool continueUTFSearch = true;
do
{
  findUTF = HTMLText.IndexOf(@"\'", findUTF + 1);
  if (findUTF != -1)
  {
    string replacedString = HTMLText.Substring(findUTF, 4);
    string esacpeddString = replacedString.Substring(2);

    int esacpeddCharValue = Convert.ToInt16(esacpeddString, 16); 
    char esacpeddChar = Convert.ToChar(esacpeddCharValue);

    esacpeddString = esacpeddChar.ToString();

    HTMLText = HTMLText.Replace(replacedString, esacpeddString);
    findUTF = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    continueUTFSearch = false;
  }
}
```