# C#: Is there any easy way to convert a string into RTF?

Tags: c#, string, converters, rtf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a string to RTF in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795709/how-to-convert-a-string-to-rtf-in-c)

I was wondering if there is an easy way convert a string to RTF in C#.

Not only the standard characters but special characters i.e. as €ƒ…†‡ to.

Comment: Have you tried System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox to convert it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795709/how-to-convert-a-string-to-rtf-in-c

Comment: @Justin Harvey: Yes, i have tried it and it gave me too much information. That problem however was solved by Marcus's answer.

Comment: Thanks for that! I knew why i trsuted the Stack-Overflow Community :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the RichTextBox control. You can set it's `Text` property to a string then get back it's `Rtf` property.