# ő becomes õ after RTF conversion in C#. Why?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, rtf

I have a method that converts strings to RTF-Strings.

For that i use the `RichTextBox` wich is provided by .NET the way it is described here:
[How to convert a string to RTF in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795709/how-to-convert-a-string-to-rtf-in-c)

When I enter `ő` it returns `{\rtf1 {'f5\f1}}`.  But that seems to be `õ` because I get that symbol, when I put it into a .rtf-file.

Why does that happen? And what can i do to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Here is the whole Method as i use it:

```
private static string ConvertToRtf(string text) {
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        richTextBox.Text = text;
        int offset = richTextBox.Rtf.IndexOf(@"\f0\fs17") + 8;
        int length = richTextBox.Rtf.LastIndexOf(@"\par") - offset;
        string result = richTextBox.Rtf.Substring(offset, length).Substring(1);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Which encoding do you use? And what encoding is the RTF string in?

Comment: I set no encoding. And i though it would be huge advantage of RTF, that it has no different encodings? btw, i attached my code to my question.

Comment: RTF is not a Unicode encoding, it predates that standard and uses a crazy charset scheme.  I can't repro your problem but we don't know anything about the default code page on your machine.  Post the entire RTF string so we can see the code page.

Comment: @HansPassant The whole RTF string of the rtfBox looks like this: {\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1031{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset238 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\\f1\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17\\'f5\\f1\\par\r\n}\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The whole RTF string of the rtfBox looks like this (etc..)

That's fine and displays correctly.  Your code snippet however doesn't make sense.  You cannot just take a sliver of RTF and hope it displays properly.  Particularly the `\f0` is important, that selects the charset.  In this case character set 238, the charset for Eastern European languages.  Note how the RTF contains the `\fonttbl` command to assign f0.

So if you copy that sliver of RTF and use it elsewhere, like in some other RTB that was **not** initialized with the same `\fonttbl` commands then you'll get a character from the wrong charset.  Like charset 0, which indeed displays `õ` instead.

Well, now you know why Unicode was invented ;)

The workaround is to only copy text from the RichTextBox.Text property.  That's Unicode.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it. I will test if this fits for our circumstances. Thanks :)