# Parsing rtf file without encoded special character

Tags: c, rtf

I have an rtf file which contains special character as it is without decode to hexadecimal or unicode. I am using lib rtf in c language.

Below is the content from the rtf file. It has not mentioned encoded mode.

\b0\fi-380\li1800 · Going to home

While parsing i will get some junk value for the character. How to get proper character from the rtf file if it contains any character in specula mode only.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b0\fi-380\li1800 \u183? Going to home
```

How to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20117501/1543816